# Remove facebook like title

Tags: css, facebook, facebook-like

Is there a way to remove the facebook "Like" button title namely "Like" and "Unlike" upon hover over?

CSS:

```
.hideLike {
   border: none;
   left: 32px;
   opacity: 0.0;
   filter: alpha(opacity=0);
   position: absolute;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="like" class="hideLike">
     <iframe src="//www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?       
      href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FXXXXXX&send=false&layout=button_count&
     width=450&show_faces=false&action=like&colorscheme=light&font&height=21"                                                                                                                                          
     scrolling="no"frameborder="0"></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: So you want to hide the like button when someone hovers over it? What would be the point of that?

Comment: nope. What I mean is, upon hover over the like button, the word/title "Like" or "Unlike" will not appear.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It would break screen readers and other accessibility software

Answer (score -1):

I posted the same question a few hours ago and I just found it. Replace the  with the  you can find in your elements. Here you have the title tag and just remove it. Here> [Remove/adjust html 'title' from facebook like button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38321264/remove-adjust-html-title-from-facebook-like-button/38322688#38322688) You can see my previous code.