# Remove/adjust html 'title' from facebook like button

Tags: javascript, php, html, facebook

I have the facebook like/share button on my site.
If I hover over the buttons it will show this title: FB: Like Facebook social plugin.

Do any of you know how I can remove or adjust this title?

This is the code:

```
 <div 

     class="fb-like" 
     data-href="https://www.facebook.com/mywebsite" 
     data-layout="button_count" 
     data-action="like" 
     data-size="small" 
     data-show-faces="true"
    data-share="true">
                </div>

JS: 

    <div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/nl_NL/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6&appId=00000000";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

I hope you can help me

Comment: I know it's only a small thing, but I think tampering with their button might violate the FB TOS.

Answer (score 0):

Just found it. Replace the  with the  you can find in your elements. Here you have the title tag and just remove it.